# animate when scroll bar reaches bottom of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop, adobe-edge

I've got two nested text boxes side-by-side with both overflow properties set to scroll (in Edge Animate).
I'm trying to make it so that when the first text box's scroll bar reaches the bottom the second text box fades in.

I'm using the scrollTop() function with no success, i.e.

```
if (sym.$('My_div').scrollTop() == 100)
{
  sym.$('My_div2').show();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
if (sym.$('My_div').scrollTop() == 100){
  sym.$('My_div2').show().fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Just added fadeOut or fadeIn and the set that to slow.